# Why JPA return null while the same query in Postgres returns a row?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, junit

I have a hard time to make my JUnit test working. Here are the code snippets.
The first is my superclass:

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class IdentifiedEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    ...
}
```

Then there are two descendeants:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"user\"")
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "user_id"))
public class User extends IdentifiedEntity {
    ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "meal")
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "meal_id"))
public class Meal extends IdentifiedEntity {
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private final User user;
    ...
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getSimpleName() + '#' + getId() + "U#" + user.getId()
                + ':' + desc + '@' + when + '×' + calories;
    }
}
```

Here is the script, creating the DB (an exceprt) in PostgreSQL:

```
create table "user" (
  user_id serial primary key,
  ...
);
```

and

```
create table meal (
  meal_id serial primary key,
  user_id int not null references "user"(user_id),
  ...
);
```

And finally the test case (a part of it):

```
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:/spring/spring-app.xml")
@Sql("classpath:/db/refill.sql")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Transactional(REQUIRED)
public class JpaMealRepositoryImplTest {
    @Test
    public void updateWithValidMeal() throws Exception {
        meal.setId(ID_MEAL_ADMINS);
        repo.update(meal);
    }
}
```

The `repo` is

```
@Repository
public final class JpaMealRepositoryImpl implements MealRepository {
    @Override
    public void update(Meal meal) throws NotFoundException {
        log.info("update({})", meal);
        Preconditions.checkArgument(!meal.isNew(), "new");
        Meal m = em.find(Meal.class, meal.getId());
        log.debug("m={}", m);
        if (m == null || m.getUser().getId() != meal.getUser().getId()) {
            throw new NotFoundException("mealId=" + meal.getId() + "; userId=" + meal.getUser().getId());
        }
        m.setWhen(meal.getWhen());
        m.setDesc(meal.getDesc());
        m.setCalories(meal.getCalories());
    }
}
```

Beware, now is the scream: the log

```
190216.874 I main/JpaMealRepositoryImpl - update(Meal#4U#1:Перекус@2018-01-26T19:02×300)
Hibernate: 
    select
        meal0_.meal_id as id1_0_0_,
        meal0_.calories as calories2_0_0_,
        meal0_."desc" as desc3_0_0_,
        meal0_.user_id as user_id5_0_0_,
        meal0_."when" as when4_0_0_,
        user1_.user_id as id1_1_1_,
        user1_.admin as admin2_1_1_,
        user1_.calories_per_day_limit as calories3_1_1_,
        user1_.email as email4_1_1_,
        user1_.enabled as enabled5_1_1_,
        user1_.name as name6_1_1_,
        user1_.password as password7_1_1_,
        user1_.registered_at as register8_1_1_ 
    from
        meal meal0_ 
    inner join
        "user" user1_ 
            on meal0_.user_id=user1_.user_id 
    where
        meal0_.meal_id=?
190216.877 D main/JpaMealRepositoryImpl - m=null

ru.javawebinar.topjava.repository.NotFoundException: mealId=4; userId=1

    at ru.javawebinar.topjava.repository.jpa.JpaMealRepositoryImpl.update(JpaMealRepositoryImpl.java:38)
    at ru.javawebinar.topjava.repository.jpa.JpaMealRepositoryImplTest.updateWithValidMeal(JpaMealRepositoryImplTest.java:61)
...
```

The **question** is: Why `190216.877 D main/JpaMealRepositoryImpl - m=null`

If I run this query in Postgres, replacing the `?` with the `meal_id` (which is `4` as seen in the log), then I get a row. Just a single row as I wanted. Why `em.find(...)` returns `null`?

Ideas?

Thank you folks!

**UPDATE**

I fill the DB with the `refill.sql` script on start each test-class:

```
@Sql("classpath:/db/refill.sql")
```

Here is the qwery I issue in `psql`:

```
select
    meal0_.meal_id as id1_0_0_,
    meal0_.calories as calories2_0_0_,
    meal0_."desc" as desc3_0_0_,
    meal0_.user_id as user_id5_0_0_,
    meal0_."when" as when4_0_0_,
    user1_.user_id as id1_1_1_,
    user1_.admin as admin2_1_1_,
    user1_.calories_per_day_limit as calories3_1_1_,
    user1_.email as email4_1_1_,
    user1_.enabled as enabled5_1_1_,
    user1_.name as name6_1_1_,
    user1_.password as password7_1_1_,
    user1_.registered_at as register8_1_1_ 
    from
        meal meal0_ 
    inner join
        "user" user1_ 
            on meal0_.user_id=user1_.user_id 
    where
        meal0_.meal_id=4;
```

The result is

```
4|400|Завтрак|1|2017-12-11 10:00:00|1|t|2000|admin@example.com|t|Admin|\x21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3|2018-01-26 22:37:08.326818+00
```

Comment: *"`meal_id` (which is `14` as seen in the log)"* No, `meal_id` is `4` in the log, not `14`.

Comment: @Andreas Yeah, you're right. Fixed

Comment: Not directly related but you've had to do alot of extra work because you're using a [PostgreSQL reserved work](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html) as a table name.  Make your life easier and don't use reserved words.

Comment: If you copy/paste the `select` statement from the log and replace `?` with `4` and then get a row, are you sure you're connected to the same database as the application, with the same user?

Comment: @Andreas Absolutelly sure. I just have no other DB

Comment: How do you persist `User` & `Meal`? Can you also add the actual result for the Postgres direct query?

Comment: @pirho Updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folks!

I fixed the issue in that way.

As I wrote my original superclass was

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class IdentifiedEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    ...
}
```

and `recreate.sql`

```
create table "user" (
  user_id serial primary key,
  ...
);
create table meal (
  meal_id serial primary key,
  user_id int not null references "user"(user_id),
  ...
);
```

The fix is in `strategy` of `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`. Here is the renewed `IdentifiedEntity`:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Access(FIELD)
abstract class IdentifiedEntity {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seqgen", sequenceName = "sequencer")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seqgen")
    private int id;
    ...
}
```

(`@Access(FIELD)` is optional)

and `recreate.sql`

```
create sequence sequencer;
create table "user" (
  user_id int primary key default nextval('sequencer'),
  ...
);
create table meal (
  meal_id int primary key default nextval('sequencer'),
  user_id int not null references "user"(user_id),
  ...
);
```

and `refill.sql`

```
...
alter sequence sequencer restart 1;
...
```

In my opinion there is the BUG in Hibernate, reproducing if `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`.

Thank you guys!

Comment: If you think it's a bug, you should try replicate it with [our templates](http://in.relation.to/2016/01/14/hibernate-jpa-test-case-template/), and if you can replicate it, open a Jira issue.

Comment: @VladMihalcea, I did what you said. It turned out the Spring influences the Hibernate working somehow. [HHH-12265](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12265)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the test should work on an isolated environment, not wipe-out the database on every run.

If you want tests to delete your current PostgreSQL schema, then you should just use the Hibernate `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` configuration property.

If you don't want Hibernate to alter the schema, then you should not set the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property.

However, are you going to rollback on each run? How are you going to work in such an environment.

It's best to start with a clean schema, populate it with data, do the test, and clear it at the end because you don't want to leave data that might interfere with other tests.

Comment: Thank you! Probably you don't know, each test-method is rolled back at its end automagically. I exactly run with a clean schema, because `refill.sql` from `@Sql("classpath:/db/refill.sql")` annotation first deletes the content of all the tables and then populates them with test data.

Comment: Are you sure they get populated? Check the logs to make sure that happens. And, is the script populating the same schema that Hibernate uses? It's not like you mentioned the bean configuration you used, so only you can figure that out.

Comment: I went to the DB and selected tables. They are filled.

Comment: Maybe Hibernate goes to a different schema.